# Flot chart: legend and font

Tags: javascript, charts, size, flot

I have configured a bar chart using the jQuery Flot library. This is the code:

```
<style>
.flot-chart-bar {
    height: 300px;
}
.flc-bar {
    font-size: 2px;
    border: 1px grey solid;

}
```

```
<div class="card profilestats" style="color: #fff !important;">
<div class="card-content" style="background-color: #bdbdbd !important;min-height:320px;">

    <div id="bar-tipoReclamo" class="flot-chart-bar"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="flc-bar" style="background-color: white; "></div>                        

</div>  
<div class="card-action" style="background-color: #757575 !important;;">
    <span>Distribuzione Tipi di Reclamo negli ultimi 3 anni</span>
</div>
```

And this is the bar:

```
        $.plot($("#bar-tipoReclamo"), barData, {
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.13,
                        order: 1
                    }
                },
                valueLabels: {
                    show: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                     ticks: [[0,currentYear-2],[1,currentYear-1],[2,currentYear]]
                },
                legend: {
                    container: '.flc-bar',
                    noColumns: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    lineWidth: 0
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                 content: " %y,%s  " ,
                    shifts: {
                        x: 20,
                        y: 0
                    },
                    defaultTheme: false
                }
            });
```

Now the question is pretty simple: how can i reduce the font size of the words inside the legend? I already tried using CSS and using some of Legend attributes that i found online but nothing seems to work.

[Bar with Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfFt7.png)

I want to reduce the font of the words inside the white legend under the bar.

Comment: Please provide a working snippet

Comment: Yes sorry. Done!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you have should work, but `font-size: 2px;` is probably not what you want.
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2gfj1uq/) for a full example based on your code where the font-size is specified in the CSS.

Comment: Already tried but the css seems to ignore the font-size command.

Comment: use !important and check

Comment: In the fiddle it works, so you need to find the difference between your code and the fiddle.